# Generating matlab array from union and replacement of two arrays

Tags: arrays, matlab

I have two large arrays which I will illustrate using the following examples.

The first array A is:

```
[ 1 21;
  3 4;
  4 12;
  5 65 ];
```

The second array B is:

```
[ 3 56;
  5 121];
```

I want to obtain the final array C as following:

```
[ 1 21;
  3 56;
  4 12;
  5 121 ];
```

i.e. replace second column of A with elements of B when available.

I am using Matlab 2007.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**MATLAB Solution**

With [`ismember`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ismember.html) -

```
C = A;
[is_present,pos] = ismember(A(:,1),B(:,1))
C(is_present,2) = B(pos(is_present),2)
```

Or use [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) to replace `ismember` -

```
[is_present,pos] = max(bsxfun(@eq,A(:,1),B(:,1).'),[],2);
```

Sample run -

```
>> A,B
A =
     1    21
     3     4
     4    12
     5    65
B =
     3    56
     5   121
     4    66
>> C = A;
[is_present,pos] = ismember(A(:,1),B(:,1));
C(is_present,2) = B(pos(is_present),2);
>> C
C =
     1    21
     3    56
     4    66
     5   121
```

---

**Bonus: NUMPY/PYTHON Solution**

You can use `boolean indexing` with [`np.in1d`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.in1d.html) -

```
import numpy as np

mask = np.in1d(A[:,0],B[:,0])
C = A.copy()
C[mask] = B
```

Sample run -

```
In [34]: A
Out[34]: 
array([[ 1, 21],
       [ 3,  4],
       [ 4, 12],
       [ 5, 65]])

In [35]: B
Out[35]: 
array([[  3,  56],
       [  5, 121]])

In [36]: mask = np.in1d(A[:,0],B[:,0])
    ...: C = A.copy()
    ...: C[mask] = B
    ...: 

In [37]: C
Out[37]: 
array([[  1,  21],
       [  3,  56],
       [  4,  12],
       [  5, 121]])
```

Comment: Sorry I don't have this functionality. Can you please provide a code for a Matlab 2007.

Comment: @user1243255 Sorry, didn't read the tags properly, edited with MATLAB code.

Comment: About to request you,, just don't dump Matlab for Numpy <kidding> :P

Comment: @SanthanSalai Well numpy is interesting thing to try out, and people there care a lot about performance which makes sense to me :)